# Discord.PY not withdrawing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def withdraw(ctx, change, amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter the amount")
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author, change)

    amount = int(amount)

    if amount>bal[1]:
        await ctx.send("You don't have enough money")
        return

    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send("YOU CAN'T WITHDRAW A NEGATIVE AMOUNT")
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author,amount)
    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount, "bank")

    await ctx.send(f"You deposited {amount} coins!")
```

Everytime I run "vb withdraw 100" all I get is "Please Enter Amount" which is weird do you guys know whats wrong and how we can fix it...

Comment: It looks like you've provided a value for the `change` arg, but not for `amount`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the `change` arg

```py
async def withdraw(ctx, amount = None):
   # ...
```

Comment: if I remove change arg then the program doesn't work it says that it needs parameter